# subprocess.CalledProcessError died with <Signals.SIGPIPE: 13>

Tags: subprocess, python-3.6, sigpipe

I'm using a python package with python subprocessing command. When I qsub several jobs in parallel, it shows the error: subprocess.CalledProcessError: died with

```
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/envs/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/anaconda3/envs/syniu/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 418, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['bismark', '/fasta', '--bowtie2', 'R1.trimed.fq.gz', '--pbat', '-o', '/M1-1-2-A3', '--temp_dir', '/M1-1-2-A3']' died with <Signals.SIGPIPE: 13>.
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/envs/bin/yap", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/anaconda3/envs/lib/python3.6/site-packages/__main__.py", line 970, in main
    func(**args_vars)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mapping/pipeline.py", line 263, in pipeline
    bismark_df = bismark(fastq_final_df, out_dir, config)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mapping/bismark.py", line 135, in bismark
    result.get()
  File "/anaconda3/envs/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 670, in get
    raise self._value
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['bismark', '/fasta', '--bowtie2', 'R1.trimed.fq.gz', '--pbat', '-o', '/M1-1-2-A3', '--temp_dir', '/M1-1-2-A3']' died with <Signals.SIGPIPE: 13>.
```

Any good suggestion?